# JavaScript RegExp for NOT foo AND NOT bar AND NOT baz

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a JavaScript RegExp object that will return true if the strings being tested DO NOT contain 'foo' and DO NOT contain 'bar' and DO NOT contain 'baz'.

This is general idea... I have a large result set. I need to do a series of function chains that will filter and flatMap using a series of RegExp.test().

The results will be:

1. One subset with all of the strings containing 'foo'.
2. One subset of all the strings containing 'bar'.
3. One subset with all of the strings containing 'baz'.
4. One subset with **everything else** (i.e. those that would fail **each**
   of the previous RegExp tests.)

I have 1 -3 working perfectly. It's finding a good way to do #4 that I'm having trouble with. I've tried doing a filter where the predicate returns

```
(false === fooRegex.test(result) && false === barRegext.text && false == bazRegex.test)
```

Not only is that cumbersome, I get several false positives.

What I want to do is something like the following psuedocode:

```
var myRegex = new RegExp('!foo && !bar && !baz', 'gi')
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If the question is about regex, could you show us the regex  you've tried writing for this? Wouldn't a few negative lookaheads work

Comment: *JavaScript RegExp for NOT foo AND NOT bar AND NOT baz* - `/^(?![\s\S]*(?:foo|bar|baz))[\s\S]*$/`

Comment: Why not just test for presence, and negate? `!string.match(/(foo|bar|baz)/)`?

Comment: Actually upon reading your question it seems like you don't really need a regular expression regardless. You appear to be classifying strings as one of four types. If your classification "falls through" the first three types, and no substrings foo/bar/baz are found, you already know it belongs to the fourth group.

Comment: If you match `foo|bar|baz` then it has that in it. If not is the else condition.

Answer (score 3):

Use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). The conjunction of negations is the negation of the disjunction.

```
!string.test(/foo|bar|baz/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var arr = 
[
'fooyay',
'baryay',
'yaybazyay',
'yay',
'blah',
'awesome',
'fooxyz',
'barxyz'
]

var fooRegex = /foo/gi
var barRegex = /bar/gi
var bazRegex = /baz/gi

var ih = []
for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++)
{
    var result = arr[x]
    if(!fooRegex.test(result) && !barRegex.test(result) && !bazRegex.test(result))
    {
        ih.push(result)
    }
}

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = ih.join('<br>')
```

It will test each item you're looking for, and if none are found, add to a list that will be displayed in the element "out".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who gave help!

I used the solution posted by **Wiktor Stribiżew** in the comments:

**JavaScript RegExp for NOT foo AND NOT bar AND NOT baz:**

```
/^(?![\s\S]*(?:foo|bar|baz))[\s\S]*$/
```

I implemented this like so:

```
var catchAllRegExp = new RegExp(/^(?![\s\S]*(?:foo|bar|baz))[\s\S]*$/, 'gi')
```

Now I simply use `catchAllRegExp.test(result)` in the predicate function passed to .filter().

**UPDATE:**

I am working in ES6 with babel / webpack. However, In ES5, the above syntax throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot supply flags when constructing one RegExp from another
```

Putting the flags directly after the regex frames solves this:

```
var catchAllRegExp = new RegExp(/^(?![\s\S]*(?:foo|bar|baz))[\s\S]*$/gi)
```

However, I think it's even better to use the shorthand:

```
var catchAllRegExp = /^(?![\s\S]*(?:foo|bar|baz))[\s\S]*$/gi;
```

Thanks again!